# Filtering and adding additional properties to array of objects

Tags: javascript, array

Hi I am working on a complex application and currently adding two additional properties to objects that match the condition and returning it back. I was able to achieve the expected output, but just wanted to know if there is any other way which is more efficient than what I have tried.

Step 1 : Filtering the array to get only car objects.

Step 2 : Add firstlayer and lastlayer prop to car objects

Step 3 :

- If it is first car object in the filtered array then mark firstlayer 
  as true.     If it is last car object in the filtered array then mark
  lastlayer as true.

Step 4 : concat it with the other non-car objects

[image]

Original array:

```
[{
  id: 10,
  name: "Truck",
  status: "Cancelled"
}, {
  id: 11,
  name: "Bus",
  status: "Approved"
}, {
  id: 12,
  name: "Car1",
  status: "Approved"
}, {
  id: 19,
  name: "Car2",
  status: "Cancelled"
}, {
  id: 13,
  name: "Car3",
  status: "Cancelled"
}]
```

Expected array:

```
[{
      id: 10,
      name: "Truck",
      status: "Cancelled"
    }, {
      id: 11,
      name: "Bus",
      status: "Approved"
    }, {
      id: 12,
      isFirstLayer: true,
      isLastLayer: false,
      name: "Car1",
      status: "Approved"
    }, {
      id: 19,
      isFirstLayer: false,
      isLastLayer: false,
      name: "Car2",
      status: "Cancelled"
    }, {
      id: 13,
      isFirstLayer: false,
      isLastLayer: true,
      name: "Car3",
      status: "Cancelled"
    }]
```

This is the code I have tried

```js
var array = [
  {
    "name": "Truck",
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Bus",
    "status": "Approved",
    "id": 11
  },
  {
    "name": "Car1",
    "status": "Approved",
    "id": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "Car2",
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "id": 19
  },
  {
    "name": "Car3",
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "id": 13
  }
];

var i=0;
var arrayLength=array.length;
var newArray = array.filter(function(a) {
  if((a.name !='Bus'&&a.name!='Truck')) 
  {   
      
      if(i==0){
    a.isFirstLayer=true;
          a.isLastLayer=false;
      }else if(i==arrayLength-i-1){
         a.isFirstLayer=false;
          a.isLastLayer=true;
      } else{
          a.isFirstLayer=false;
          a.isLastLayer=false;
      }
      i++;
  };
  return a
});

console.log(newArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fierce_trailblazer/q2uvf06r/24/

Any suggestions to improve the code would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I noticed:

`Array.prototype.filter` is intended to be used when you want to filter out elements from an array and construct a new array from certain elements of the other array, for example:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const evens = arr.filter(num => num % 2 === 0);
console.log(evens);
```

If you're not taking elements out to make a new array, then `.filter` isn't appropriate. If you're just looking to *iterate*over an array and perform side-effects (like mutate certain elements), use `Array.prototype.forEach` or `for..of` instead.

That said - I think using `filter` *would* be the best way to approach this problem, by separating out the cars from non-cars. More on that later.

You have

```
if((a.name !='Bus'&&a.name!='Truck'))
```

```
if(i==0){
```

```
}else if(i==arrayLength-i-1){
```

It would be better to never use sloppy comparison with `==` and `!=` - instead, use strict comparison with `===` and `!==`. The problem with sloppy comparison is that it has [so many weird rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494) a developer has to memorize in order to be confident in its proper usage. See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35MpY.png). If you're comparing items of the same type, using strict comparison instead will work just fine. (When comparing items of different types, you can check their types and then explicitly cast to the same type if needed, then perform the comparison.)

I'd also recommend adding spaces between operators - it improves code readability. (Many decent IDEs can do this automatically.) Eg, compare

```
if((a.name !='Bus'&&a.name!='Truck'))
```

to

```
if (a.name !== 'Bus' && a.name !== 'Truck')
```

(There's no need for the extra `()`s around the condition)

An even better method might be to check whether the item's name starts with `Car`:

```
if (a.name.startsWith('Car'))
```

You're missing a semicolon with `return a`. Occasionally forgetting semicolons can [result in confusing bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi), especially if you aren't an expert. Consider using a linter to automatically prompt you to fix these sorts of potential mistakes.

If I were approaching this problem, I'd prefer to separate out the cars into their own array. This separation can be achieved concisely with `Array.prototype.filter`. Then, iterate over the cars, and add the `isFirstLayer` and `isLastLayer` properties (as `false`) to each car. Then, take the *first* car and set its `isFirstLayer` to `true`. Similarly, take the *last* car and set its `isLastLayer` to `true`:

```js
var array = [{
    "name": "Truck",
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Bus",
    "status": "Approved",
    "id": 11
  },
  {
    "name": "Car1",
    "status": "Approved",
    "id": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "Car2",
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "id": 19
  },
  {
    "name": "Car3",
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "id": 13
  }
];
const cars = array.filter(item => item.name.startsWith('Car'));
for (const car of cars) {
  car.isFirstLayer = false;
  car.isLastLayer = false;
}
cars[0].isFirstLayer = true;
cars[cars.length - 1].isLastLayer = true;
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be a better idea to use a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to initially add the properties to a subset of the elements of the array. Finally you can change the last element from the new Array with a property `isLastLayer`. I used `Array.find` within the reducer lambda and a custom function `findLast` for finding the last array-element with property `isLastLayer`.

```js
const result = document.querySelector("#result");
const log = (...txt) => result.textContent += txt.join("\n") + "\n";

// moved to function, so the relevant code is more visible
const array = getTestArray();

// find the last element using the predicate lambda
const findLast = (array, predicate) => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (predicate(array[i])) {
      return array[i];
    }
  }
};

// reduce the values, adding the layer props to 
// all elements where the name does not start 
// with 'bus' or 'truck'. Use Array.find within the 
// accumulated array to determine if isFirstLayer
// is already in the set of elements
let newArray = array.reduce((acc, value) => {
  if (/^(bus|truck)/i.test(value.name)) {
    return [...acc, value];
  }
  const isFirst = !acc.find(el => "isFirstLayer" in el);
  value = { ...value,
    isFirstLayer: isFirst,
    isLastLayer: false
  };
  return [...acc, value];
}, []);

// use findLast to find the last element with
// a property 'isLastLayer' in the array, and 
// change its value
findLast(newArray, el => "isLastLayer" in el).isLastLayer = true;

// let's see if it worked
log(JSON.stringify(newArray, null, 2));

function getTestArray() {
  return [{
      "name": "Truck",
      "status": "Cancelled",
      "id": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Bus",
      "status": "Approved",
      "id": 11
    },
    {
      "name": "Car1",
      "status": "Approved",
      "id": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Car2",
      "status": "Cancelled",
      "id": 19
    },
    {
      "name": "Car3",
      "status": "Cancelled",
      "id": 13
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

It can also be done without the extra `findLast` function

```js
const result = document.querySelector("#result");
const log = (...txt) => result.textContent += txt.join("\n") + "\n";
const array = getTestArray();
let accumulator = {
  newArr: [], 
  // track first/last
  firstLayerSet: false,
  lastLastLayer: null
};
const addPropsReducer = (acc, value, i) => {
  if (/^(bus|truck)$/i.test(value.name)) {
    return {
      newArr: [...acc.newArr, value]
    };
  }
  value = { ...value,
    isFirstLayer: !acc.firstLayerSet,
    isLastLayer: false
  };
  return {
    ...acc,
    newArr: [...acc.newArr, value],
    firstLayerSet: true,
    lastLayerIndex: i
  };
};

let newArray = array.reduce(addPropsReducer, accumulator);
newArray.newArr[newArray.lastLayerIndex].isLastLayer = true;

// ditch tracking values
newArray = newArray.newArr;

log(JSON.stringify(newArray, null, 2));

function getTestArray() {
  return [{
      "name": "Truck",
      "status": "Cancelled",
      "id": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Bus",
      "status": "Approved",
      "id": 11
    },
    {
      "name": "Car1",
      "status": "Approved",
      "id": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Car2",
      "status": "Cancelled",
      "id": 19
    },
    {
      "name": "Car3",
      "status": "Cancelled",
      "id": 13
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Play with this code in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/Ltyknpwg/).